# Applying a custom master page in SP2010 breaks all internal links

Tags: custom-masterpage

I created a custom master page in Designer 2010 and the links work fine when I apply the master to a single site page for testing. But when I assign it as the default master page, many pages produce 404 errors, even built-in ones like the Site Pages listing.

EDIT - Here is the code:

```
<%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/Welcome.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="MUISelector" src="~/_controltemplates/MUISelector.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="DesignModeConsole" src="~/_controltemplates/DesignModeConsole.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="<%$Resources:wss,language_value%>" dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%>" runat="server" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" __expr-val-dir="ltr">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
<meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"/>
<title id="onetidTitle">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/>
</title>
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="4"/>
<SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:ULSClientConfig runat="server"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _fV4UI = true;
    </script>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:SPPageManager runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:SPHelpPageComponent Visible="false" runat="server"/>
<style type="text/css">
.hoverMenu {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.topMenu {
    font-family: Georgia;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.dropMenu {
    font-family: Georgia;
    background-color : #eeeeee;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
.dropHoverMenu {
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 2px;
}
.staticMenu {
    border: 1px gray solid;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: -8px;
    margin: 0px;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
    margin: -1px auto 0;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
/* ---------- Mega Drop Down --------- */
#mega {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 60px -1px 0 0;
    z-index: 200;
}
#mega li {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-left: -1px;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#mega li:hover {
    background: #eee;
    border-bottom: 0;
padding: 7px 0 1px 0;
    margin-top: -7px;
    z-index: 1; 
}
#mega a {
    color: #000;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
}


#mega div {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 0;
}
#mega div.var {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 0;
}
#mega li:hover div {
    left: -1px;
    top: auto;
}
#mega li.dif:hover div {
    left: -221px;
}

#mega div h2 {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 330px;
    position: relative; /* makes above drop shadow */
}
#mega div.var h2 {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    position: relative; /* makes above drop shadow */
}
#mega div p {
    float: left;
    width: 106px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative; /* makes above drop shadow */
}
#mega div p a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%; /* For IE6/7 */
    ;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
#mega div a:hover, #mega div a:focus, #mega div a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
</head>

<body scroll="no" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" class="v4master">
<form runat="server" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}">
  <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" enablepagemethods="false" enablepartialrendering="true" enablescriptglobalization="false" enablescriptlocalization="true" />
  <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager id="m" runat="Server"/>
  <SharePoint:SPNoScript runat="server"/>
  <div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display: none" class="s4-notdlg noindex"> <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-TurnOnAcc" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>
    </a></div>
  <div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display: none" class="s4-notdlg noindex"> <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-TurnOffAcc" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>
    </a></div>
  <div class="s4-notdlg s4-skipribbonshortcut noindex"> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:this.href='#startNavigation';" class="ms-SkiptoNavigation" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,skipribbon_accesskey%>" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,skipRibbonCommandsLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>
    </a></div>
  <div class="s4-notdlg noindex"> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:this.href='#mainContent';" class="ms-SkiptoMainContent" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,maincontent_accesskey%>" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,mainContentLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>
    </a></div>
  <a id="HiddenAnchor" href="javascript:;" style="display: none;"></a>
  <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="GlobalNavigation"/>
  <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
    <div id="s4-ribboncont">
      <SharePoint:SPRibbon runat="server" PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer" CssFile="">
        <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowLeft"
                CssClass="ms-siteactionscontainer s4-notdlg"> <span class="ms-siteactionsmenu" id="siteactiontd">
          <SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>" id="SiteActionsMenuMain"
                        PrefixHtml=""
                        SuffixHtml=""
                        MenuNotVisibleHtml="&amp;nbsp;"
                        >
            <CustomTemplate>
              <SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate runat="server"
                            FeatureScope="Site"
                            Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
                            GroupId="SiteActions"
                            UseShortId="true"
                            >
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_EditPage"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpage%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescriptionv4%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ActionsEditPage.png"
                                MenuGroupId="100"
                                Sequence="110"
                                ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(false);"
                                />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_TakeOffline"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_takeoffline%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_takeofflinedescription%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/connecttospworkspace32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="100"
                                Sequence="120"
                                />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_CreatePage"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createpage%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createpagedesc%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/NewContentPageHH.png"
                                MenuGroupId="200"
                                Sequence="210"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('Page')) { OpenCreateWebPageDialog('~site/_layouts/createwebpage.aspx') }"
                                PermissionsString="AddListItems, EditListItems"
                                PermissionMode="All" />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_CreateDocLib"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdoclib%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdoclibdesc%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/NewDocLibHH.png"
                                MenuGroupId="200"
                                Sequence="220"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('DocLib')) { GoToPage('~site/_layouts/new.aspx?FeatureId={00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101}&amp;ListTemplate=101') }"
                                PermissionsString="ManageLists"
                                PermissionMode="Any"
                                VisibilityFeatureId="00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101" />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_CreateSite"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createsite%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createsitedesc%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/newweb32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="200"
                                Sequence="230"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('Site')) { STSNavigate('~site/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx') }"
                                PermissionsString="ManageSubwebs,ViewFormPages"
                                PermissionMode="All" />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Create"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_create%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdesc%>"
                                MenuGroupId="200"
                                Sequence="240"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="if (LaunchCreateHandler('All')) { STSNavigate('~site/_layouts/create.aspx') }"
                                PermissionsString="ManageLists, ManageSubwebs"
                                PermissionMode="Any" />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/allcontent32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300"
                                Sequence="302"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"
                                PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                                PermissionMode="Any" />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_EditSite"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editsite%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editsitedescription%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/SharePointDesigner32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300"
                                Sequence="304"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="EditInSPD('~site/',true);"
                                PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages"
                                PermissionMode="Any"
                            />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_SitePermissions"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,people_sitepermissions%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sitepermissiondescriptionv4%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/Permissions32.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300"
                                Sequence="310"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/user.aspx"
                                PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions"
                                PermissionMode="Any" />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Settings"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,settings_pagetitle%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sitesettingsdescriptionv4%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/settingsIcon.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300"
                                Sequence="320"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/settings.aspx"
                                PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
                                PermissionMode="Any" />
                <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_CommitNewUI"
                                Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_commitnewui%>"
                                Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_commitnewuidescription%>"
                                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/visualupgradehh.png"
                                MenuGroupId="300"
                                Sequence="330"
                                UseShortId="true"
                                ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="GoToPage('~site/_layouts/prjsetng.aspx')"
                                PermissionsString="ManageWeb"
                                PermissionMode="Any"
                                ShowOnlyIfUIVersionConfigurationEnabled="true" />
              </SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate>
            </CustomTemplate>
          </SharePoint:SiteActions>
          </span>
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
                            runat="server"
                            ID="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout"
                            IconUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                            IconAlt="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbIconAlt%>"
                            IconOffsetX=0
                            IconOffsetY=112
                            IconWidth=16
                            IconHeight=16
                            AnchorCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor"
                            AnchorOpenCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor-open"
                            MenuCss="s4-breadcrumb-menu">
              <div class="s4-breadcrumb-top">
                <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="s4-breadcrumb-header" Text="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbHeader%>" />
              </div>
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
                                    runat="server"
                                    SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
                                    RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
                                    PathSeparator=""
                                    CssClass="s4-breadcrumb"
                                    NodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbNode"
                                    CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
                                    RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbRootNode"
                                    NodeImageOffsetX=0
                                    NodeImageOffsetY=353
                                    NodeImageWidth=16
                                    NodeImageHeight=16
                                    NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                                    RTLNodeImageOffsetX=0
                                    RTLNodeImageOffsetY=376
                                    RTLNodeImageWidth=16
                                    RTLNodeImageHeight=16
                                    RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                                    HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
                                    SkipLinkText="" />
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
            <div class="s4-die">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server" Visible="false"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          <SharePoint:PageStateActionButton id="PageStateActionButton" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
        <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowRight"
                ID="RibbonTabRowRight"
                CssClass="s4-trc-container s4-notdlg">
          <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ID="GlobalDelegate0" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink0" />
          <a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="display:none"></a><a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="display:none"></a>
          <div class="s4-trc-container-menu">
            <div>
              <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"> </wssuc:Welcome>
              <wssuc:MUISelector ID="IdMuiSelector" runat="server"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" ID="GlobalDelegate2" Scope="Farm" runat="server" />
          <span> <span class="s4-devdashboard">
          <Sharepoint:DeveloperDashboardLauncher
                ID="DeveloperDashboardLauncher"
                NavigateUrl="javascript:ToggleDeveloperDashboard()"
                runat="server"
                ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
                Text="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_launchdevdashalt_text%>"
                OffsetX=0
                OffsetY=222
                Height=16
                Width=16 />
          </span> </span> </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
      </SharePoint:SPRibbon>
    </div>
    <div id="notificationArea" class="s4-noti"> </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SPNavigation" runat="server">
      <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PublishingConsole" Id="PublishingConsoleDelegate"> </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div id="WebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="WebPartAdderUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <WebPartPages:WebPartAdder ID="WebPartAdder" runat="server"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="WebPartAdder" />
        </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="s4-workspace">
    <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
      <div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle">
        <div class="s4-title s4-lp">
          <div class="s4-title-inner">
            <table class="s4-titletable" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="s4-titlelogo"><SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
                    <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png" runat="server"/>
                  </SharePoint:SPLinkButton></td>
                <td class="s4-titletext"><h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">
                      <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
                        <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
                      </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                  </h1>
                  <span id="onetidPageTitleSeparator" class="s4-nothome s4-bcsep s4-titlesep">
                  <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/>
                  </span>
                  <h2>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
                  </h2>
                  <div class="s4-pagedescription" tabindex="0">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />
                  </div></td>
                <td class="s4-socialdata-notif"><SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="s4-topheader2" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg"> <a name="startNavigation"></a>
          <div id="s4-searcharea" class="s4-search s4-rp">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
              <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"/>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <span class="s4-help"> <span style="height: 17px; width: 17px; position: relative; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;" class="s4-clust"> <a href="#" style="height: 17px; width: 17px; display: inline-block;" onclick="TopHelpButtonClick('HelpHome');return false" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>" id="TopHelpLink" title="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server"> <img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" style="left: -0px !important; top: -309px !important; position: absolute;" align="absmiddle" border="0" runat="server" /></a></span> </span></div>
          <div class="s4-rp s4-app"> </div>
          <div class="s4-lp s4-toplinks">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
              <h2 class="ms-hidden">
                <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,topnav_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>
              </h2>
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server">
                <div id="wrap">
                  <ul id="mega">
                    <li><a href="/SitePages/Home.aspx">Home</a> <b class="s4"></b></li>
                    <li class="style1"><a href="#">News</a> <b class="s4"></b>
                      <div> <b class="s1"></b><b class="s2"></b><b class="s3"></b> <a href="/Lists/List1/">List1</a> <a href="/Lists/List2/">List2</a> <a href="/Lists/List3/">List3</a> </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a> <b class="s4"></b>
                      <div> <b class="s1"></b><b class="s2"></b><b class="s3"></b> <a href="/Lists/List1/">List1</a> <a href="/Lists/List2/">List2</a> <a href="/Lists/List3/">List3</a> </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a> <b class="s4"></b>
                      <div> <b class="s1"></b><b class="s2"></b><b class="s3"></b> <a href="/Lists/List1/">List1</a> <a href="/Lists/List2/">List2</a> <a href="/Lists/List3/">List3</a> </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sites</a> <b class="s4"></b>
                      <div> <b class="s1"></b><b class="s2"></b><b class="s3"></b> <a href="/Lists/List1/">List1</a> <a href="/Lists/List2/">List2</a> <a href="/Lists/List3/">List3</a> </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="s4-statusbarcontainer">
        <div id="pageStatusBar" class="s4-status-s1"> </div>
      </div>
      <SharePoint:VisualUpgradePreviewStatus runat="server"/>
      <div id="s4-mainarea" class="s4-pr s4-widecontentarea">
        <div id="s4-leftpanel" class="s4-notdlg">
          <div id="s4-leftpanel-content"> 
            <!--                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" runat="server" />
                                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">
              <div style="text-align: center"> <br />
                <br />
                <a href="/SitePages/page1.aspx"> Page 1<br />
                <img src="/SiteAssets/page1.png" style="border: 0px" /></a><br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="/SitePages/page2.aspx"> Page 2<br />
                <img src="/SiteAssets/page2.png" style="border: 0px" width="60" height="60" /></a><br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="/SitePages/page3.aspx"> Page 3<br />
                <img src="/SiteAssets/page3.png" style="border: 0px" width="55" height="55" /></a><br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="/SitePages/page4.aspx"> Page 4<br />
                <img src="/SiteAssets/page4.png" style="border: 0px" /></a><br />
                <br />
              </div>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="s4-ca s4-ca-dlgNoRibbon" id="MSO_ContentTable">
          <div class="s4-die">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server" visible="false" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server" Visible="false"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrame" class="ms-pagetitleareaframe s4-pagetitle"> </div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" runat="server" visible="false" />
            <span class="s4-die">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server" visible="false" />
            </span>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server" visible="false" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" runat="server" Visible="false"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='138' height='1' /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarBorder" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server" Visible="false"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </div>
          <SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder UIVersion="3" ID="DesignModeConsoleV3" runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="WSSDesignConsole" runat="server">
              <wssuc:DesignModeConsole id="IdDesignModeConsole" runat="server" />
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder>
          <div class="s4-ba">
            <div class="ms-bodyareacell">
              <div id="MSO_ContentDiv" runat="server"> <a name="mainContent"> </a>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="s4-die">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <SharePoint:DeveloperDashboard runat="server"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <input type="text" name="__spText1" title="text" style="display: none;" />
  <input type="text" name="__spText2" title="text" style="display: none;" />
</form>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:WarnOnUnsupportedBrowsers runat="server"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your master page code so we can check it?

Comment: What links are you talking about? What's the URL in the address bar when you get 404?

Comment: The Site Page links work fine, but none of the Library or List links work anywhere on the site. I even went to the page _layouts/viewlsts.aspx (which still has the old master page) and none of the links for site content work either. For any of the broken links, I get a 404 message but the URL is the intended one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by starting from scratch - I created a new copy of the default master page and added the custom HTML again. Looks like my original attempt above had HTML outside of the content place holders. I also switched to a linked style steet instead of an embedded one.